# How do DropdownList work in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have worked with Webform DropDownList and find MVC dropdownlist little confusing to work with:

Questions:

1. - Have MVC dropdownlist a server side event for indexchange , selecteditemChange as WebForms?
2. - How to get TEXT and VALUE of a dropdownList selecteditems  in a controller (as I understand, I only can get selected value in a controller and not text)?

Comment: Is the text unique? If so, can you set the Value field equal to the Text?

Comment: A `<select>` submits the `value` of its selected `<option>` element. If you want to submit "Danmark" or "Sverig" etc then set the `Value` property of `SelectListItem` to it - `new SelectListItem {Text="Danmark", Value="Danmark"},` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remember that everything you can do in ASP.NET web forms you can do in ASP.NET MVC. The only difference is the process of getting there.Here are the answers to your questions:

1. The simple answer is no.You would need to handle the change using javascript and do an ajax call to the server if you want to notify the server of the change.
2. You can get both the TEXT and the VALUE of the drop down item in the controller.

And here is the code example:

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DropExample()
    {
        var fruits = new List<SelectListItem>();
        fruits.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Orange", Value = "1" });
        fruits.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Banana", Value = "2" });
        fruits.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Grapes", Value = "3" });

        ViewBag.Fruits = fruits;

        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetJsonData(string value,string text)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        string message = String.Format("You have selcted - {0}({1}).This is from the server...",text,value);
        return Json(new {Message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#fruit').change(function () {        
            var value = $(this).val();
            var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();

            var message = "You selcted - " + text + "(" + value + ").Now let's notify the server...";
            alert(message);

            $.getJSON("/Home/GetJsonData?value=" + value + "&text=" + text, null, function (data) {
                $("#result").empty();
                $("#result").html(data.Message);
            });

        });

    });
</script>
@Html.DropDownList("fruit", ViewBag.Fruits as List<SelectListItem>)
<div id="result"></div>
```

In ASP.NET web forms we were spoiled with the server side events and controls for the benefit of rapid application development but would hit a brick wall every time we would need to slightly alter the events or the way the controls looked and behaved.In MVC we don't have that problem because we have the full control of the HTML that get's generated, it might seem like a lot of work at first doing things the MVC way but it has huge benefits down the line when you receive very custom requirements from clients.That's one of the major reasons why MVC is so popular

Comment: Very interesting.

-1-
But you have in your code written "ViewBag.Fruits as List <SelectListItem>", it is necessary. I think that a drop down list loading data automatically from the View object?

-2-
You have created a funtion - public JsonResult GetJsonData (string value, string text)

How can we use it to display data on Page or save in database ?

Right now  your Javascript shows data on the Site.


I close the question after your answer

Comment: I'm not going to write all the code for you.I already answered your questions and showed you code examples.If you want to know how to insert values into a database then google it first and make an effort to figure it out yourself and ONLY if you're having problems doing it then ask a new question on stack overflow

Comment: Sorry, .. now I understand your code. I know how to save  data to database now
.
But you can tell why you write ViewBag.Fruits as List <SelectListItem> ... why is it nessery ?

Comment: It's just one of the ways of binding to a drop down in MVC.You don't have to do it that way.You can create a model and pass it to the view and then bind a property on the model to the drop down.Have a look at this article for various ways of binding to a drop down in mvc - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/ways-to-bind-dropdown-list-in-Asp-Net-mvc/